# Sort associated Hierarchy with already sorted Contours in OpenCv in Python

Tags: python, opencv, hierarchy, contour

I am extracting innermost Contours from an Image(**input.png**) by using the following Code
(*I am using **Python 3.6.3** and **opencv-python==3.4.0.12***)

**input.png**

[image]

```
import copy
import cv2

BLACK_THRESHOLD = 200
THIN_THRESHOLD = 10
ANNOTATION_COLOUR = (0, 0, 255)

img = cv2.imread('input.png')
orig = copy.copy(img)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, 6)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh=BLACK_THRESHOLD, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Find the contours
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

hierarchy = hierarchy[0]  # get the actual inner list of hierarchy descriptions
idx = 0
# For each contour, find the bounding rectangle and extract it
for component in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    currentContour = component[0]
    currentHierarchy = component[1]
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(currentContour)
    roi = img[y+2:y + h-2, x+2:x + w-2]
    # Skip thin contours (vertical and horizontal lines)
    if h < THIN_THRESHOLD or w < THIN_THRESHOLD:
        continue
    if h > 300 and w > 300:
        continue
    if h < 40 or w < 40:
        continue
    if currentHierarchy[3] > 0:
        # these are the innermost child components
        idx += 1
        cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', roi)
```

**Result:**
[image]

As you can see extracted Images are not in any particular order. So to fix this I ***sorted contours*** on the basis of their ***x-axis coordinates***. Below is the code:

```
import copy
import cv2

BLACK_THRESHOLD = 200
THIN_THRESHOLD = 10
ANNOTATION_COLOUR = (0, 0, 255)

img = cv2.imread('input.png')
orig = copy.copy(img)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, 6)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh=BLACK_THRESHOLD, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Find the contours
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Sort Contours on the basis of their x-axis coordinates in ascending order
def sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right"):
    # initialize the reverse flag and sort index
    reverse = False
    i = 0
    # handle if we need to sort in reverse
    if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        reverse = True
    # handle if we are sorting against the y-coordinate rather than
    # the x-coordinate of the bounding box
    if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        i = 1
    # construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to
    # bottom
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
    (cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
                                        key=lambda b: b[1][i], reverse=reverse))
    # return the list of sorted contours
    return cnts


sorted_contours = sort_contours(contours)

idx = 0
# For each contour, find the bounding rectangle and extract it
for component in sorted_contours:
    currentContour = component
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(currentContour)
    roi = img[y + 2:y + h - 2, x + 2:x + w - 2]
    # Skip thin contours (vertical and horizontal lines)
    if h < THIN_THRESHOLD or w < THIN_THRESHOLD:
        continue
    if h > 300 and w > 300:
        continue
    if h < 40 or w < 40:
        continue
    idx += 1
    print(x, idx)
    cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', roi)
```

**Result:**

[image]

This has sorted the contours perfectly. But now as you can see I am getting all the Contours(*that is the reason of two copies of each digit*) ***because I am not using Hierarchy*** but when I spent some time debugging I realized that ***only Contours are sorted but not their associated Hierarchy***. So can anyone please tell me how to sort Hierarchy along with Contours so that I can get only the innermost Contours of the sorted Contours. Thank You!

Comment: +1 and kudos for asking a coherent question, accompanied with [mcve]s, samples, and all the other important details! I only wish more questions in [tag:opencv] were of this quality.

Comment: Thank you so much for that really appreciate that.
Can you guide me regarding this problem? @DanMašek

Comment: Hold on, playing with it now. A simple answer would be indirect sort (as in, sort an array of indices of the contours), but your first script was quite close, and we can take another approach. | I just got held up by a weird issue -- apparently having a script named `numbers.py` caused my numpy to fail to load :D

Comment: Lol, I can understand and do you mean kind of parallel sorting? @DanMašek

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `copy` module... `orig = img.copy()` does a deep copy (the images are represented as numyp arrays).

Comment: No, i didn't mean parallel sorting. Indirect sort simply means that you're sorting a separate array of numerical indices of the elements (while using the element's values to determine the order), rather than sorting the elements itself. This is useful when the cost of moving the elements around it memory is high, or in case like this where the reorganization would break other relationships.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that copy is not required(*it was redundant*) it has fastened up things and now I get what you meant by indirect sorting. Kudos @DanMašek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with your first script, since that gave you good results that just were not sorted correctly.

Observe that the only decision based on the hierarchy (when you decide whether or not to treat given contour as a digit) is `currentHierarchy[3] > 0` Why don't we begin by selecting only the contours that match this criterion, and perform further processing only on this subset (not having to care about hierarchy any more).

```
# Find the contours
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

hierarchy = hierarchy[0]  # get the actual inner list of hierarchy descriptions

# Grab only the innermost child components
inner_contours = [c[0] for c in zip(contours, hierarchy) if c[1][3] > 0]
```

---

Now we're left only with the contours we're interested, we just have to sort them. We can reuse a simplified version of your original sorting function:

```
# Sort Contours on the basis of their x-axis coordinates in ascending order
def sort_contours(contours):
    # construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to bottom
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in contours]
    (contours, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(contours, boundingBoxes)
       , key=lambda b: b[1][0], reverse=False))
    # return the list of sorted contours
    return contours
```

and get sorted contours:

```
sorted_contours = sort_contours(inner_contours)
```

---

Finally, we want to filter out the garbage and output the good contours correctly labelled:

```
MIN_SIZE = 40
MAX_SIZE = 300
THIN_THRESHOLD = max(10, MIN_SIZE)
PADDING = 2

# ...

idx = 0
# For each contour, find the bounding rectangle and extract it
for contour in sorted_contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    roi = img[(y + PADDING):(y + h - PADDING), (x + PADDING):(x + w - PADDING)]
    # Skip thin contours (vertical and horizontal lines)
    if (h < THIN_THRESHOLD) or (w < THIN_THRESHOLD):
        continue
    if (h > MAX_SIZE) and (w > MAX_SIZE):
        continue
    idx += 1
    cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', roi)
```

---

**Full Script** (using Python 2.7.x and OpenCV 3.4.1)

```
import cv2

BLACK_THRESHOLD = 200
MIN_SIZE = 40
MAX_SIZE = 300
THIN_THRESHOLD = max(10, MIN_SIZE)
FILE_NAME = "numbers.png"
PADDING = 2

# ============================================================================

# Sort Contours on the basis of their x-axis coordinates in ascending order
def sort_contours(contours):
    # construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to bottom
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in contours]
    (contours, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(contours, boundingBoxes)
       , key=lambda b: b[1][0], reverse=False))
    # return the list of sorted contours
    return contours

# ============================================================================

img = cv2.imread(FILE_NAME)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Don't use magic numbers
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh=BLACK_THRESHOLD, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Find the contours
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

hierarchy = hierarchy[0]  # get the actual inner list of hierarchy descriptions

# Grab only the innermost child components
inner_contours = [c[0] for c in zip(contours, hierarchy) if c[1][3] > 0]

sorted_contours = sort_contours(inner_contours)

idx = 0
# For each contour, find the bounding rectangle and extract it
for contour in sorted_contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    roi = img[(y + PADDING):(y + h - PADDING), (x + PADDING):(x + w - PADDING)]
    # Skip thin contours (vertical and horizontal lines)
    if (h < THIN_THRESHOLD) or (w < THIN_THRESHOLD):
        continue
    if (h > MAX_SIZE) and (w > MAX_SIZE):
        continue
    idx += 1
    cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', roi)
```

and the images it produced:

[image: Screenshot of thumbnails of output images]

Comment: Worked Like a charm. Such a simple yet amazing approach unlike what I was thinking initially. Thank you so much @DanMašek

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but is there anyway to keep hierachy order synchornous with the contour order? Because i want to use hierachy to check if the inside of object is filled or not...

Comment: @HungDang An indirect sort would do the job. Or you could merge the controur and hierarchy data together (say using `zip` function) and sort the result.

Comment: Thanks i just added the hierarchy variable after ````boundingBoxes```` like code below. And it worked :)

Comment: ````def sort_contours_hierarchy(contours, hierarchy):
    # construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to bottom
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in contours]
    (contours, boundingBoxes, hierarchy) = zip(*sorted(zip(contours, boundingBoxes,hierarchy)
       , key=lambda b: b[1][0], reverse=False))
    # return the list of sorted contours
    return (contours, np.array(hierarchy))````